# angular5-data-table error with paging and sorting

Tags: angular5, angular-datatables

I am using angular5-data-table with my angular 5 application.(https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular5-data-table)

This is my code

```
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <data-table id="my-table"
            title = "Test Table"
            [items] = "testData"
            [itemCount] = "testCount"
            [expandableRows]="true"
            [substituteRows]="false"
            [sortAsc]="true"
            [limit]=10
      >
            <data-table-column
                  [property]="'name'"
                  [header]="'Name'"
                  [sortable]="true">
            </data-table-column>
            <data-table-column
                  [property]="'age'"
                  [header]="'Age'"
                  [sortable]="true">
            </data-table-column>
      </data-table>
</div>
```

[This is my output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AzCKA.png)

Here i set rows limit as 10. But it showing all the data. In the bottom of the table Result is saying '1 to 10 of 12' but it's showing all the rows. Also it's not supporting with sorting.

Angular CLI: 1.7.4
Node: 8.11.1
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 5.2.10

Answer (score 1):

Handle reload event in your data-table

In your HTML

```
<data-table (reload)="reloadItems($event)">
```

In your component

```
reloadItems(params){
    if(!this.tableResource) return;
    this.tableResource.query(params).then(items => this.items = items);
}
```